# how to call stored procedure from SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I want to create a SSIS package which will call the stored procedure and dump the output of the procedure into table.

SSIS package will return the output and i need this resultset ouput to dump into another table.
But before inserting i want to update the rows from that tables if any rows exist for that date or then insert the resultset.

Comment: Execute SQL Task is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do't quite understand your requirements but you could do it this way:

1. Drop on an execute SQL Task
2. Ensure that `YourStagingTable` exists and columns match the stored procedure output

Here is some sample code to put in your Execute SQL Task that does what you want:

```
-- Clear Staging Table
TRUNCATE YourStagingTable

-- Save results of stored proc into staging table
INSERT INTO YourStagingTable
EXEC YourProc

-- Update any existing records
UPDATE YourFinalTable
SET YourUpdateField = YourStagingTable.YourSourceField
FROM YourStagingTable
WHERE YourFinalTable.JoinField1 = YourStagingTable.JoinField1

-- Insert any non existing records
INSERT INTO YourFinalTable (Column1,Column2)
SELECT Column1,Column2
FROM YourStagingTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM YourFinalTable 
    WHERE YourFinalTable.JoinField1 = YourStagingTable.JoinField1
    )
```

Comment: Source table & Destination table both are in different Database.

Comment: As ling as they are on the same server, simply qualify them: `db.schema.table`